# How to write to a file from JavaBeanObject (Generics)

Tags: java

I want to know how to write to a file from an object(generics) using BufferedWriter.

I tried below code but its not working.

I want to print all the values present in the List. Whether i need to do any type casting or use iterator and use get method or use for loop.

If i done any wrong what is the way to write values to the file other than PrintWriter.I have tried using different writers but nothing worked for me.
I am not understanding the way to proceed.

Taken from my program which is getting wrong output

```
    public static void file()throws Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for (int i = 0; i < AllList.a.size(); i++) {

            JavaBeans b1 = AllList.a.get(i);
    bw.write(b1.getProductDescription());
    bw.flush();
    bw.close()
```

PART II:

```
    package com.collections;

    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class AllList {
        public static List<JavaBeans> a = new ArrayList<JavaBeans>();
        public static void getAllList() {


        JavaBeans j = new JavaBeans();
        j.setProductNumber(1);
        j.setProductName("car");
        j.setProductDescription("for driving");
        j.setProductUnits(10);

        JavaBeans j1 = new JavaBeans();
        j1.setProductNumber(2);
        j1.setProductName("soap");
        j1.setProductDescription("for bathing");
        j1.setProductUnits(20);

        JavaBeans j2 = new JavaBeans();
        j2.setProductNumber(3);
        j2.setProductName("Cell");
        j2.setProductDescription("for calling");
        j2.setProductUnits(30);

        a.add(j);
        a.add(j1);
        a.add(j2);

        Iterator<JavaBeans> it = a.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
                {
            JavaBeans bean = it.next();
            System.out.print(bean.getProductNumber()+ " \t   "+bean.getProductDescription()+"\t"+bean.getProductName()+"\t"+bean.getProductUnits()+"\n");
        }
        }

        public static void add(JavaBeans bean )
        {
        a.add(bean);

            System.out.println("added succesfully");        
        }

        public static void update(JavaBeans bean )
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllList.a.size(); i++) {

            JavaBeans b = AllList.a.get(i);

            if(b.getProductNumber()==bean.getProductNumber()){
                AllList.a.set(i, bean);
            }}

        }   

        public static void delete(JavaBeans bean )
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllList.a.size(); i++) {

            JavaBeans b = AllList.a.get(i);

            if(b.getProductNumber()==bean.getProductNumber()){
                AllList.a.remove(i);
                System.out.println("deleted succesfully");
            }}

    }

    public static void file()throws Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for (int i = 0; i < AllList.a.size(); i++) {

            JavaBeans b1 = AllList.a.get(i);
    bw.write(b1.getProductDescription());
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    }





                }


    }
```

JAVABEAN CLASS:

```
package com.collections;

public class JavaBeans {

    private int productNumber;
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private int productUnits;


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((productDescription == null) ? 0 : productDescription.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((productName == null) ? 0 : productName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + productNumber;
        result = prime * result + productUnits;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        JavaBeans other = (JavaBeans) obj;
        if (productDescription == null) {
            if (other.productDescription != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!productDescription.equals(other.productDescription))
            return false;
        if (productName == null) {
            if (other.productName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!productName.equals(other.productName))
            return false;
        if (productNumber != other.productNumber)
            return false;
        if (productUnits != other.productUnits)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JavaBeans [productNumber=" + productNumber + ", productName=" + productName + ", productDescription="
                + productDescription + ", productUnits=" + productUnits + "]";
    }

    public int getProductNumber() {
        return productNumber;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public int getProductUnits() {
        return productUnits;
    }

    public void setProductNumber(int productNumber) {
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductUnits(int productUnits) {
        this.productUnits = productUnits;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be `BufferedWriter`? Are you simply storing the values in text or something? Why not make the your object `Serializable` and write your object to a file via `ObjectOutputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want **readable text** to be crated, I recommend writing with a PrintWriter - this adds control over newlines to your code.